# Redirect to specified action if requested action was not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can I redirect Action which is not found in controller into another action within the same controller? Let's say that file `abc.txt` is requested via `http://localhost:5000/Link/GetFile/abc.txt`. My controller correctly serving that file. But now, i need to handle request such as `http://localhost:5000/Link/Document/abc`. Of course there is no any action matched to `Document` so I need to invoke function `Error` within the same controller (including id from original request).

I tried to solve this with `StatusCodePagesWithReExecute` function but then my `File` action is not working (each request goes directly to Error function).

I have following controller:

```
public class LinkController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult GetFile(string id)
    {
        return DownloadFile(id);
    }

    public IActionResult Error(string id)
    {
        return File("~/index.html", "text/html");
    }

    private FileResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
    {
        IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@mypath);

        IFileInfo fileInfo = provider.GetFileInfo(fileName);
        var readStream = fileInfo.CreateReadStream();
        return File(readStream, "text/plain");
    }
}
```

and startup configuration:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
    DefaultContentType = "application/octet-stream",
});

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
        );

});
```

Any clues how to solve this problem?
Regards

Comment: why not redirect from error function then?

Comment: Yes you are right, I can redirect from error, this actually solve my problem. I think my brain is overload for few days and I don't see obvious :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UseStatusCodePages` to achieve a simple redirection whenever there's a 404. Here's what it looks like:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(ctx =>
{
    if (ctx.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 404)
        ctx.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Path/To/Your/Action");

    return Task.CompletedTask;
});
```

Just add this somewhere above `UseMvc`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

I´m sorry, my first answer was not correct.

1. `IRouteCollection router = RouteData.Routers.OfType<IRouteCollection>().First();`

with this, you can match an url to controller action

2. Create HttpContext for testing (example with injection)

   ```
   private readonly IHttpContextFactory _httpContextFactory;

   public HomeController(
       IHttpContextFactory httpContextFactory)
   {
       _httpContextFactory = httpContextFactory;
   }
   ```
3. Create the context with values

   ```
   HttpContext context = _httpContextFactory.Create(HttpContext.Features);
   context.Request.Path = "/Home/Index";
   context.Request.Method = "GET";
   ```
4. Check route

   ```
   var routeContext = new RouteContext(context);
   await router.RouteAsync(routeContext);
   bool exists = routeContext.Handler != null;
   ```

Further reading: https://joonasw.net/view/find-out-if-url-matches-action